# Response 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: android, http

I used to get the following response to php request

Response:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

my code:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://myappdemo.com/payumoney/payUmoneyHashGenerator.php");

     // get the payuConfig first
     String postParam = postParams[0];

     byte[] postParamsByte = postParam.getBytes("UTF-8");

     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
     String.valueOf(postParamsByte.length));
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     conn.getOutputStream().write(postParamsByte);

     InputStream responseInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
     StringBuffer responseStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
     byte[] byteContainer = new byte[1024];
     for (int i; (i = responseInputStream.read(byteContainer)) != -1; ) {
     responseStringBuffer.append(new String(byteContainer, 0, i));
        }

     Log.e("tag", "doInBackground: "+ responseStringBuffer.toString());
```

also tried with volley reponse was

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301 for
>   http://myappdemo.com/payumoney/payUmoneyHashGenerator.php

.

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php`?

Comment: the request was php

Comment: check your url, try with https insted http in url

Answer (score 3):

`301 Moved Permanently` is used for permanent URL redirection.Current links using the URL that the response is received for should be updated. try to use `https://` in your link

use  `URL url = new URL("https://myappdemo.com/payumoney/payUmoneyHashGenerator.php");`