# trying to read JSON data from url causes url redirection

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to read date from JSON using a URL , but it throws an exception. and the response from header is `301 Moved Permanently`

this basically means the there is something wrong with link, but I cannot figure out what it is exactly since the API provider did not mention anything in regard to changes to their API

Any help is appreciated.

here is my code

```
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
```

```
String url = "http://webservice.fanart.tv/v3/movies/" + movie.id + "?api_key=" + apikey;
        List<String> enClearLogos = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl(url));
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("hdmovielogo");
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject movieObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if (movieObject.getString("lang").equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
                    enClearLogos.add(movieObject.getString("url"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here example

```
{
    "name": "The Bad Guys",
    "tmdb_id": "629542",
    "imdb_id": "tt8115900",
    "hdmovieclearart": [
        {
            "id": "362695",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovieclearart/the-bad-guys-6231fd4379a87.png",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "6"
        },
        {
            "id": "362696",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovieclearart/the-bad-guys-6231fd53d3a96.png",
            "lang": "ru",
            "likes": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "367992",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovieclearart/the-bad-guys-6280fb431126b.png",
            "lang": "cz",
            "likes": "2"
        }
    ],
    "hdmovielogo": [
        {
            "id": "369396",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-629dc8e4da93a.png",
            "lang": "fr",
            "likes": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "368375",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-62899cfba2c00.png",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "371110",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-62bdec1d38353.png",
            "lang": "es",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "355025",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-61ba168a41d9b.png",
            "lang": "ru",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "355031",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-61ba1f851cd32.png",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "355032",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-61ba1f96a497e.png",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "366828",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-626984d807f4d.png",
            "lang": "cz",
            "likes": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "360922",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/hdmovielogo/the-bad-guys-6217a7c5ba60d.png",
            "lang": "it",
            "likes": "0"
        }
    ],
    "movieposter": [
        {
            "id": "367357",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-6274ea20dcc86.jpg",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "371114",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-62bdecfbd6715.jpg",
            "lang": "es",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "368000",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-628108a944560.jpg",
            "lang": "pt",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "367358",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-6274ea33e2ed5.jpg",
            "lang": "00",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "355026",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-61ba169a2b57e.jpg",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "358210",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-61ee6f9a14706.jpg",
            "lang": "00",
            "likes": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "367991",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-6280fb200c5bf.jpg",
            "lang": "cz",
            "likes": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "367990",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/movieposter/the-bad-guys-6280fb1ba6d39.jpg",
            "lang": "cz",
            "likes": "0"
        }
    ],
    "moviethumb": [
        {
            "id": "371117",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviethumb/the-bad-guys-62bdee5332ad2.jpg",
            "lang": "es",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "367994",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviethumb/the-bad-guys-6280fb7b224fd.jpg",
            "lang": "cz",
            "likes": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "370972",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviethumb/the-bad-guys-62bbbc9385121.jpg",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "367260",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviethumb/the-bad-guys-6272bfb851ca5.jpg",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "0"
        }
    ],
    "moviebackground": [
        {
            "id": "355027",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviebackground/the-bad-guys-61ba16ab7df92.jpg",
            "lang": "",
            "likes": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "367177",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviebackground/the-bad-guys-6271f6e99b835.jpg",
            "lang": "",
            "likes": "0"
        }
    ],
    "moviedisc": [
        {
            "id": "367993",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviedisc/the-bad-guys-6280fb602b271.png",
            "lang": "cz",
            "likes": "1",
            "disc": "1",
            "disc_type": "bluray"
        },
        {
            "id": "358213",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviedisc/the-bad-guys-61ee85436574f.png",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "0",
            "disc": "1",
            "disc_type": "bluray"
        }
    ],
    "moviebanner": [
        {
            "id": "358216",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviebanner/the-bad-guys-61ee93348cb62.jpg",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "370973",
            "url": "https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/629542/moviebanner/the-bad-guys-62bbbd7215d83.jpg",
            "lang": "en",
            "likes": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

exception message

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:168)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)
```

Comment: Please include the full exception message and stack trace in the question text

Comment: Obviously, JSON you're trying to parse is invalid. Try to print it on the console.

Comment: it is the exact same thing on the console. I just did `curl 'https://webservice.fanart.tv/v3/movies/629542?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: yes just like that , so what should it look like normally?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the sample-JSON is valid, it should be parsed fine (I've tried it). But exception should have a reason, either something is missing or something gets added to it.

Comment: you are right , I appreciate it , I did a little digging , I think it has sth to do with some sort of protection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http://` causes url redirection and throws this message in the header response (301 Moved Permanently) so I had to use `https://` instead now everything works nicely.

more info here [Response 301 Moved Permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167467/response-301-moved-permanently)